# Vagrant provider specific variables

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

In a vagrantfile I would like to set some provider specific variables. After realising that I cannot set the values in these sections ([because of this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/XIxGdm78s4I/5gFFKoIIS4wJ)):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, override|
    ...
end
```

... this is my workaround - Basically I set an environment variable that I can check and then set the provider settings accordingly:

```
  if ENV['VAGRANT_PROVIDER'] == 'virtualbox'

    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    tld = "local"
    dbadmin_pass = "vagrant"

  elsif ENV['VAGRANT_PROVIDER'] == 'aws'

    config.hostmanager.enabled = false
    tld = "com"
    dbadmin_pass = "myprodpass" 

  else

    raise Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError.new, "Missing environment variable or invalid value: VAGRANT_PROVIDER [virtualbox|aws]"

  end
```

This is really hacky though and requires me to set the environment variable as well.

I'm not a ruby expert at all - Is there a better way to set provider specific variables?

Answer (score -1):

You can define providers like:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    tld = "local"
    dbadmin_pass = "vagrant"
end

config.vm.provider :aws do |aws|
    config.hostmanager.enabled = false
    tld = "com"
    dbadmin_pass = "myprodpass" 
end
```

Then start your vagrant with:

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

or

```
vagrant up --provider=aws
```

Make sure you override any provider specific variables, see the [Vagrant Docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/configuration.html) - Overriding Configuration section.

Comment: I'm aware of provider configuration and how it works - but it doesn't answer my question as the code in your example would not work. Have you tried it yourself or followed the link in the question at all?